# How to read formula including turtle values from a input box?

Tags: netlogo

Im having trouble including a formula in the input box into my model and hoped someone could help. In short I want the global variable "subsidy_absolute_threshold" to be read as "100 + m2 / 1600". So that wherever that variable is implemented, that code is implemented instead. The current code reads something like

```
turtles-own [m2 subsidy_eligible]
globals [subsidy_absolute_threshold]
[...]
set subsidy_absolute_threshold "100 + m2 / 1600"
[...]
ask turtles [
if ambition < read-from-string subsidy_absolute_threshold [set subsidy_eligible true]
]
```

Technically the global value is an input box set as a string, but it should be functionally the same thing. The error message I get is "Extra characters after literal." which I struggle to understand.
I have tried all the "types" of input boxes, but none work. I have also tried directly writing in the formula, as in replacing subsidy_absolute_threshold with 100 + m2 / 1600, which works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the native command `runresult` instead of `read-from-string`.

I'm somewhat unsure exactly why read-from-string does not work, so if someone wants to present an explanation please do.

Comment: `read-from-string` is intended for use where only simple values are expected. `runresult` is intended for use where arbitrary reporter expressions are expected.

Comment: Arguably the language doesn't need to include both since for any string that `read-from-string` accepts, `runresult` would return the same answer. But in situations where `read-from-string` is adequate for solving a problem, it is preferable because 1) it is faster (since it doesn't need to handle arbitrary code), 2) it is safer (because there is no possibility of running arbitrary code), 3) it more clearly indicates to anyone reading the code what kind of input is expected.